# Vue <router-view /> doesn't show anything

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

So I deploy this app in my server using sub directories like `MyServer.com/vue/`.

Inside my App.vue only show `<router-view />`, on local this application runs smoothly, and there is no error on console.

App.vue:

```html
<template>
  <router-view/>
</template>

<script>
export default { };
</script>

<style></style>
```

route.js:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: () => import("../views/Home.vue"),
    redirect: "/dashboard",
    children: [
      // Children routes
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    component: () => import("../views/Login.vue"),
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
  mode: 'hash',
});

export default router;
```

main.js:

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./route";
import ElementPlus from "element-plus";
import { Chart, registerables } from "chart.js";
import "element-plus/dist/index.css";
import "./styles/index.scss";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);
app.use(ElementPlus);
app.use(Chart.register(...registerables));

app.mount("#app");
```

Comment: Any error that's showing up?

Comment: No error, just blank screen @Amaarrockz

Comment: Try to test [base option](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base) of vue router. maybe [this link](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-set-root-base-url-for-a-vuejs-project/7682/12) also could help you.

Comment: does it show the login page when you go to /login? 
I can imagine that it doesn't work because you redirect to /dashboard which is no available route?

Comment: I think maybe you need to change your ```vue.config.js``` file. maybe changing [publicpath](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) could help you.